# How to align social like buttons next to copyright text inside footer?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I followed this [example](https://gist.github.com/howtomakeaturn/290057120966900fb21a11a48b4c7e93) from a github gist to align social like buttons at the same height but I am not sure why it's not aligning next to my copyright text.  It's showing the buttons under new row but I'd like it to show on the same row as the copyright text.  I am also using Bootstrap for this. How do I fix this?

html:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="copyright text-muted">Copyright ©2016 example.com. All Rights Reserved</span>
    <div class="social">  
      <span class="twitter">
        <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.example.com">Tweet</a>
      </span>
      <span class="Facebook"><iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://gist.github.com/thebigreason/1296097&amp;show_faces=false&amp;layout=button_count" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="height: 21px; width: 100px" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        </span>
      <span class="google">
        <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300"></div>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

css:

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
/* This gets Google to fall into place */
.social {
    font-size: 1px;
}
/* This gets Facebook to fall into place */
.social iframe {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
/* Set an optional width for your button wrappers */
.social span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 110px;
}
/* Adjust the widths individually if you like */
.social .google {
    width: 75px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bayman/pLLnxczk/)

Comment: check this out https://jsfiddle.net/pLLnxczk/1/ see it in large screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this css.

```
.container span, .container .social {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the css for `copyright` as well, and in edit in `social` class, add the following css:

```
.copyright{display:inline-block;}
```

Add the display:inline-block to this following class

```
.social {font-size: 1px; display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap grid system to get two columns next each other, so you wrap your copyright with col-md-6 like this :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <span class="copyright text-muted">Copyright ©2016 example.com. All Rights Reserved</span>
</div>
```

and same thing with social:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="social">  
      ...
    </div>
</div>
```